Cannot access my server when one WireGuard interface is closed if there is another WireGuard interface up
I am attempting to use ProtonVPN via WireGuard on an Ubuntu 22.04 server. I have multiple different ProtonVPN-generated WireGuard configurations, each connecting to a different location. The problem that I have is that if I have two or more WireGuard interfaces up and I bring one down, I completely lose access to the server (cannot access any web pages the server is hosting, nor can I ssh into it). This occurs until all other WireGuard interfaces are brought down or until an additional WireGuard interface is brought up.
Here is the template for one of my ProtonVPN WireGuard configurations:
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Address = 10.2.0.2/32
DNS = 10.2.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx

I am using wireguard-tools v1.0.20210914.
Thank you!

do the wireguard configs have any preup/postup/predown/postdown commands? all of them have AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0? If you have multiple WG interfaces up, how would your system know which one to use
